Price Options are being converted to prices with Tax included, instead of net prices although "Display Prices" = "Excluding Tax"
I have the following Problem:
in Magento Version 2.4.5-p3, an Example Product in my shop has the following options:
<select name="options[1452]" id="select_1452" class="required product-custom-option admin__control-select" 
title="" data-selector="options[1452]" aria-required="true">
  <option value="">-- Bitte auswählen --</option>
  <option value="6160" price="0">option1</option>
  <option value="6161" price="17.72">option2 +17,72&nbsp;€</option>
  <option value="6162" price="63.28">option3 +63,28&nbsp;€</option>
</select>

after I updated to Magento Version 2.4.7-p2, the same Product has the same options when the page loads, but these get changed by a JavScript (1) function to be displayed as gross prices with Tax included:
<select name="options[1452]" id="select_1452" class=" required product-custom-option admin__control-select" 
title="" data-selector="options[1452]" aria-required="true">
  <option value="">-- Bitte auswählen --</option>
  <option value="6160" price="0">option1</option>
  <option value="6161" price="17.72">option2 +21,26&nbsp;€</option>
  <option value="6162" price="63.28">option3 +75,94&nbsp;€</option>
</select>

(1) ./vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-options.js
Excerpt of the product page (html), here one can see the oldPrice and finalPrice are gross prices.
...
<script type="text/x-magento-init">{
    "#product_addtocart_form": {
        "priceOptions": {
            "optionConfig": {
                "1452": {
                    ...
                    "6161": {
                        "prices": {
                            "oldPrice": {
                                "amount": 21.264001,
                                "adjustments": []
                            },
                            "basePrice": {
                                "amount": 17.72
                            },
                            "finalPrice": {
                                "amount": 21.264001
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "fixed",
                        "name": "option2"
                    },
                    ...
                }
            },
            "controlContainer": ".field",
            "priceHolderSelector": "[data-product-id='1393'][data-role=priceBox]"
        }
    }
}</script>

The Function needPriceConversion (2) checks if prices need to be converted or not.
(2) .\vendor\magento\module-tax\Model\Config.php
in Version 2.4.5-p3 this function returns false and in the version 2.4.7-p2 it returns 2. So in the 2.4.5-p3 Shop, the net prices are returned and in the 2.4.7-p2 shop the prices are returned with tax included (gross).

So now I am wondering if this behavior is correct, and if it is, how do I need to change my options to get Magento to return the product options as it did before the update?

